# How can I use the clause of selection from two tables, joing them and showing the result one of them?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I select the data from one table, but also I need to use the clause of selection of another one:

sql & php:

```
  $condition = "
AND CONCAT_WS('-    ', products_description.products_id, products_attributes.products_attributes_id) = '".$product_number."' 
OR products_description.products_id = '".$product_number."'";

    $show_products_query_string = "
SELECT 
    products_description.products_id AS id,
    products_description.products_name AS product_name, 
    products.products_image AS product_image 
FROM 
    products_description 
    LEFT JOIN products ON products_description.products_id = products.products_id  
    LEFT JOIN warehouse_products ON products_description.products_id = warehouse_products.id" . $filter.$condition;
```

In this query I need to show only what I select: id, name, image_name.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: where is the problem exactly? you have the selected fields in the query and everything seems to be fine...

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: @Jakolcz,for example: when I select only from one table I get the 100 rows, but when I use the clause from the second, joing it to the first one I get 300 rows, I need this to be shown as 100 rows, but using the clause from the second table. Thanx